# TSQL - dynamic copy table structure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a cycle I should transform:

```
SELECT * INTO #copiaTabella FROM #TABELLA WHERE 1 = 2
```

in dynamic

```
EXECUTE('SELECT * INTO #copiaTabella FROM ' + @sNomeTabella_APPO + ' WHERE 1 = 2')
```

So it does not work. Is there a way to do that?
Thank you

Comment: It depends on your ultimate aim. It fails because `#copiaTabella` is scoped to the `EXECUTE()` so does not exist outside of it.

Comment: I should then do this:   `code` DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
  SELECT @cols += N',' + name --+ ' ' + system_type_name
  FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('SELECT * FROM #copiaTabella', NULL, 1);

  SET @cols = STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, N''); `code`

Comment: Can you define "it does not work"?

Comment: If I run:
select * from #copiaTabella
I get:
Invalid object name '#copiaTabella'.

Comment: Look at you WHERE clause.  1 does not equal 2 so the query will not run,

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze actually this will work. Using select into with that where predicate will create the target table with no rows.

Comment: LOL the temp table you create in your dynamic sql is out of scope once you leave your dynamic sql.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks, good to know

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that temporary objects which are created in the dynamic T-SQL statement are not visible for the outer scope. For example, the following will raise an error:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'CREATE TABLE #TEST ([a] INT);'

SELECT *
FROM #TEST;
```

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 3 Invalid object name '#TEST'.

If you need to create different table structure each time, you must include the rest of the T-SQL manipulation in the dynamic T-SQL statement as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with:

If you need to create different table structure each time, you must include the rest of the T-SQL manipulation in the dynamic T-SQL statement as well.

Comment: If you need to create such table and then to do some stuff with it (insert/deleted/select) just add these operations in the dynamic T-SQL, too and execute them all.

Comment: So it works:

 `code`EXECUTE('SELECT * INTO ##copiaTabella FROM' + @sNomeTabella_APPO + ' WHERE 1 = 2')
 
 DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
 SELECT @cols += N',' + name --+ ' ' + system_type_name
 FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('SELECT * FROM ##copiaTabella', NULL, 1);

 SET @cols = STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, N'');

 print(@cols)  
 drop table ##copiaTabella

For now I have solved, thanks to everyone!